# IndexError: tuple index out of range when comparing lists

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to convert an improper 3X3 magic square to a proper 3X3 magic square. This is my code:

```
from itertools import *
def ms():
    magic_squares = [
    [8,1,6],[3,5,7],[4,9,2],
    [6,1,8],[7,5,3],[2,9,4],
    [4,3,8],[9,5,1],[2,7,6],
    [2,7,6],[9,5,1],[4,3,8],
    [2,9,4],[7,5,3],[6,1,8],
    [4,9,2],[3,5,7],[8,1,6],
    [6,7,2],[1,5,9],[8,3,4],
    [8,3,4],[1,5,9],[6,7,2]
    ]
    for p in permutations(range(1,10)):
        if all(sum(p[i] for i in r) == 15 for r in magic_squares):
           yield list(p)
def closest_ms(m):
    m = sum(m, [])
    return min(ms(), key = (lambda x: sum(i != j for i,j in zip(m,x))))
s = []
smo = []
for s_i in range(3):
    s_t = [int(s_temp) for s_temp in input().strip().split(' ')]
    s.append(s_t)
important_var = closest_ms(s)
print(important_var)
```

As you can see, since there are 8 proper 3X3 magic squares, I am trying to use the eight of them to convert an improper magic square into a proper magic square by the minimal changes that are possible(using the digits 1-9). For example, I have a magic square like this:

```
[[5,3,4],[1,5,8],[6,4,2]]
```

And the output should be like this with the minimal changes:

```
[[8,3,4],[1,5,9],[6,7,2]]
```

But my code is giving me this error:`IndexError: tuple index out of range` in line 14

How can i get past this error and make my code work as intended?

Comment: On which line??

Comment: Shouldn't magic square has always numbers 1-9 in it; one occurrence of each. If diagonally, vertically or horizontally the sum of numbers is not 15, it is not proper magic square.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't think about your algorithm but I can see that the problem is here:

```
all(sum(p[i] for i in r) == 15 for r in magic_squares)
```

Each r is a 3-element list containing digits 1-9.  So the possible values of i range from 1-9.  But p is a permutation of the digits 1-9 and therefore p is tuple with 9 elements.  The indices of p range from 0-8.